# Change the first field of the first row of a grid with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a one page html empty, one controller angular and one service angular.
In my service I have implemented a grid with bootstrap, with 8 columns. when i put in my data i create 8 rows with all the same fields each other.

i want to understand how change the html code of the first line in the first field.

an example could be:

i have a table 8x8 when i click on first field of first row it show me the string "Hello" and when i click on other first field it show me the string "Good".

Simply i want change the html code row of a table already implemented with bootstrap, the first row.

Comment: Are you implementing the `table` using `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Post your code which you have implemented

Comment: Yes, i create the column in angular service and I implements rows with repeat.